# Angular - Tooltip does not show for disabled buttons in Chrome

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have this code for buttons and I want to shows the tooptips for disabled button. This works fine in Firefox and IE, but does not work in Chrome. In Chrome, only the buttons that are enabled showed the tooltip.

```
<div *ngFor"let btn of buttons">
   <button [tooltip]="'Tooltip'" [disabled]="btn.disable">
</div>
```

Comment: this may help, https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1025

Comment: this may also helps, http://jsfiddle.net/mihaifm/W7XNU/200/

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48277909/angular-material-how-to-add-a-tooltip-to-a-disabled-button

Answer (score 13):

This solution works for me:

```
<div *ngFor"let btn of buttons">
   <div [tooltip]="'Tooltip'">
      <button class='btn' [disabled]="btn.disable">
   </div>
</div>

<style>
   .btn:disabled{
      pointer-events: none;
   }
<style>
```

Comment: This is also how I would have done it, but please consider leaving some explanation about what the code actually does, detailed answers get upvoted quickly.